# Textview comes on top Imageview

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to add a `TextView` and an `ImageView` in a `RelativeLayout`, as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/bg_message2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/mUser"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mUserImg"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_profile_message"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The above code looks like this: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vhsc.png]

and What I want : [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVDIK.jpg]

how do I prevent the `TextView` being underlaid on the `ImageView`?

Comment: @helldawg13 weights only work in LinearLayouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the ImageView in place, then set the TextView.
You can give the TextView a width of "match_parent", because it will fill just the **remaining** space.

So:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mUserImg"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_profile_message"
    />
    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/bg_message2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/mUserImg"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/mUser"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it works when I add `layout_toLeftOf="@id/mUserImg"` Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Modify like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/bg_message2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/mUser"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mUserImg"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_profile_message"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can reduce and increase the value of layout_weight depending on your needs

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mUserImg"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_message2"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mUserImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:background="@drawable/bg_profile_message" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Removed the double `background` attribute in the ImageView

Answer (score -1):

You can with this for your TextView :

```
layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

and this for right side for your ImageView :

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

**EDIT**

And you can add this for your `TextView`:

```
layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mUserImg"
```